# How to make program allow as input on the command-line a space-separated list of integers (JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, command-line-arguments, args

I've never worked with the command-line up until now, and have no idea how to use it. Right now I'm running an InsertionSort program on eclipse and have declared my array of integers in my driver as :

```
 int arr[] = {99, 37, 17, 5, 12, 33};
```

How would I go about allowing this input on the command line instead and printing the results out that way instead? I use a MAC if that matters. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  You probably want to use the `Scanner` class.  There are a number (no pun intended) of ways to do this.

Comment: Simple google search finds [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) so I'm afraid that I have to http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am asked to not use Scanner

Comment: Then you can try `java YourProgramClass 99 37 ...` and then access those numbers in `String[] args`.

Answer (score 2):

one possible way:

```
public class Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String arg : args) {
            try {
                intList.add(Integer.parseInt(arg));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("not an integer: " + arg);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(intList);
    }
}
```

then:

```
$ javac Numbers.java
$ java Numbers 3 6 4
[3, 6, 4]
```